# Object.create vs new

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects, javascript-inheritance

The following code works when I create my object with the constructor but when I do object.Create it doesn't get initialized properly. `functionName is not a function`. I have two questions. Why isn't the object.create working ?

How would I organize my code within the same Calculator Function so I could use both new and object.create ?

I know I can add the methods to Calculator.prototype and do Object.create but I was wondering if my code can be changed within the current structure to allow for both ?

```
//var calc = new Calculator();
var calc = Object.create(Calculator);


function Calculator(){
    this.array = [];
    this.results = 0;

    this.calculate = function(){    
        try{
        results = eval(this.array.join(''));
        this.array = [results];
        return results; 
        }
        catch(error){
            alert('Wrong arguments provided');
            return this.array.join('');
        }
    },

    this.isNumber = function(str){
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(str)) && isFinite(str);
    },

    this.addToOperationsArray = function(str){
        if (this.array.length <= 0 && !this.isNumber(str)){ // Don't add operand before any number.
            return; 
        }

        this.array.push(str);

    },
    this.clearEverything = function(){
        this.array = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.create` expects a prototype that is, an object. `Calculator` isn't only a constructor but also a function object. So you merely  pass a function object to `Object.create`, which isn't invoked.

Comment: @LUH3417 Damn! I just invoked the function inside the Object.create and it works.

Comment: Um, It shouldn't work, because `Calculator` doesn't return anything. Please show the invocation.

Comment: You are right. I think the page didn't get refreshed properly. Tried again and it is not working or maybe you jinxed it.

Comment: Ok so if I explicitly return this in my constructor. Invoking it directly in Object.create works. WTF !!!  More confusion.

Comment: If you're in strict mode `Calculator` would just return `undefined` (or the window object in normal mode). You just can't use `Object.create` with constructors. Look into [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I get your point. I thought "this" is implicit returned in object.create as well but it is only for the constructor. This definitely guided me to the right direction. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no constructor invocation with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

You can get similar results in a multitude of ways. See if something along these lines helps you:

```
function Calculator() {
  this.array = [];
  this.results = 0;
}
Calculator.prototype = {
  calculate: function() {
    try {
      results = eval(this.array.join(''));
      this.array = [results];
      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Wrong arguments provided');
      return this.array.join('');
    }
  },
  isNumber: function(str) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(str)) && isFinite(str);
  },
  addToOperationsArray: function(str) {
    if (this.array.length <= 0 && !this.isNumber(str)) { // Don't add operand before any number.
      return;
    }

    this.array.push(str);

  },
  clearEverything: function() {
    this.array = [];
  }
};

// create using 'new'
var calc1 = new Calculator();

// create using 'Object.create'
// the constructor function is not called
// but properties of returned object can be passed to the function, and
// you can control the enumerable, writable, configurable properties
var calc2 = Object.create(Calculator.prototype, {
  'array': {
    value: [],
    enumerable: true
  },
  'results': {
    value: 0,
    enumerable: true
  }
});

// create using 'Object.create'
// and invoke the constructor with 'call',
// explicitly setting 'this'
var calc3 = Object.create(Calculator.prototype);
Calculator.call(calc3);


console.log(calc1);   // Calculator {array: Array[0], results: 0}
console.log(calc2);   // Object {array: Array[0], results: 0}
console.log(calc3);   // Object {array: Array[0], results: 0}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer to my previous question was the key to all of this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.create() //This for inherit the parent object
```

what you want is to instantiate the object, you can do it like this:

```
var calc = new Calculator() //This will inherit it's prototype and execute the constructor for you.
```

**Object.create** works with **new** side by side not against. Just to make it **more clear** about prototype inheritance and instantiate, let's take step back, I'll provide you with **example**:

```
// CREATE || Object.create for inheritence by prototyping
var Thing = function (name) {
  this.type = "universal";
  this.name = name;
}

Thing.prototype = {
  say: function(something) {
    console.log(this.name + " say something " + something);
  },
  check_soul: function (){
    console.log(this.name + " soul is " + this.type);
  }
}

// constructor for God
var God = function(name){
  Thing.call(this, name); // Execute parent constructor also with current context
  this.type = "pure"; // overwrite the type
}

God.prototype = Object.create(Thing.prototype); // inherit God from Thing
God.prototype.constructor = God; // implement the constructor


// constructor for Demon
var Demon = function(name){
  Thing.call(this, name);
  this.type = "corrupted";
}

Demon.prototype = Object.create(Thing.prototype, {
  say: {
    value: function(something){ // Overwrite Thing prototype for say
    console.info(this.name + " say: Let's destory " + something + "!");
  }}
}); // inherit Demon from Thing
Demon.prototype.constructor = Demon;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NEW || new for instantiation
var anonymous = new Thing("Anonymous");
anonymous.check_soul();

var god = new God("Zeus");
god.check_soul();
god.say("omni");

var demon = new Demon("Lucifer");
demon.check_soul();
demon.say("human");
```

Example above is too verbose? (ES2015 here to help) note that this can only apply on node v6 and above.

```
// CREATE || Object.create for inheritence by prototyping

'use strict';

class Thing {
  constructor (name){
    this.type = "universal";
    this.name = name;
  }

  say(something) {
    console.log(this.name + " say something " + something);
  }

  check_soul() {
    console.log(this.name + " soul is " + this.type);
  }
}

class God extends Thing { // inherit God from Thing and implement the constructor
  constructor (name){
    super(name); // Execute parent constructor also with current context
    this.type = "pure"; // overwrite the type
  }
}

class Demon extends Thing { // inherit Demon from Thing and implement the constructor
  constructor (name){
    super(name); // Execute parent constructor also with current context
    this.type = "corrupted"; // overwrite the type
  }

  say(something) { // Overwrite Thing prototype for say
    console.info(this.name + " say: Let's destory " + something + "!");
  }
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NEW || new for instantiation
var anonymous = new Thing("Anonymous");
anonymous.check_soul();

var god = new God("Zeus");
god.check_soul();
god.say("omni");

var demon = new Demon("Lucifer");
demon.check_soul();
demon.say("human");
```

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late, may be you have noticed, but in your implementation theres is at least one side effect in the code `Calculator.prototype.constructor` this will point to `Object.prototype.constructor` instead of the Calculator constructor, what are you doing is overwriting every property of the prototype chain, it is best practice to use dot notation to add new properties `Calculator.prototype.method = () => { // some code }`